# Inserting a page with a different paper size

Tags: latex

I am writing a report in LaTeX and want to insert a page at the end containing a summary of the content. Of course the summary will contain a lot of data so I want to add a page with another paper size (A3,...). But I don't find any solution on the internet for that problem. Is there a solution to this problem or do I have to write an additional LaTeX file with that summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\par\vfill\break % Break Last Page 

\advance\vsize by 8cm % Advance page height 
\advance\voffset by -4cm % Shift top margin 
% Start big page 
Some text
% End big page 
\par\vfill\break % Break the page with different margins 

\advance\vsize by -8cm % Return old margings and page height 
\advance\voffset by 4cm % Return old margings and page height
```

Answer (score 1):

I think setting all page parameters after a page flush (aka eject) should work, but I haven't tried it. Start with \paperwidth and \paperheight. You can try using the geometry package and issuing another \geometry{...} command.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the page as a separate PDF and then include it with either `\includegraphics` or the `pdfpages` package.

Comment: `\includegraphics` will not enlarge the page size. I'm not sure about `pdfpages`, though.

Comment: `\includepdf` (`pdfpages`) will not enlarge the page size by default either.